# How to match 10 numbers with or without spaces with Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex expression that matches 10 digits. However, this digit can contain numerous spaces on different places.

A couple of examples that it needs to match are:

7 367151 029

7367151079

60 124 44 11 0

1223 123 5678

As you can see, the spaces are completely random, and there is no way to say how many spaces there will be present. There can also be a lot spaces before the actual digits.

What I have so far is: .*([\d ]{13})

However, this also counts spaces, which results in the regex expression missing the first couple of digits.

Furthermore, it is important that it matches the first 10 numbers, since there is a possibility that a string looks like this:

ESADF 310912 1 23 9 EKJL 129301234812.

Comment: Quite simple: `[\d ]{10}`

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is that it gets the last 10 characters, including spaces. So it misses the first couple of digits if those are present.

Comment: What language are you using to implement this RegExp?

Comment: I am using python!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you expect a match in `ESADF 310912 1 23 9 EKJL 129301234812`?

Comment: In that case use a beginning anchor to make sure you start matching at the beginning of the string: `^[\d ]{10}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight variation on @Tranbi's solution, this works even if there is more than one space separating the digits.

`(\d\s*?){10}`

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should work:

```
^(\s?\d\s?){10}
```

If you want to strip leading and trailing whitespaces, and find the sequence anywhere in the string (and not only at the beginning):

```
\d(\s?\d\s?){8}\d
```

Comment: Probably better as a non-capturing group: `^(?:\s?\d\s?){10}`

Comment: Sure, capturing is useless in this case. It makes the Regex easier to understand though. Feel free to edit my answer if you think it's appropriate.